# Azure KeyVault Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am getting an error when I try and resolve my keys.

```
KeyVaultKeyResolver cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(GetToken);
string keyvaultUrl = Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("KeyVaultUrl");
var rsa = cloudResolver.ResolveKeyAsync(keyvaultUrl, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };
```

The exception says:

```
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
User Name: uberserve
Message: Operation "get" is not allowed
Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<Do>d__11b`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetKeyAsync>d__5d.MoveNext()
```

The implementation follows http://blogs.technet.com/b/kv/archive/2015/06/02/azure-key-vault-step-by-step.aspx

I'm not quite sure where I went wrong here.  Advice please.

The access policy was configured per the blog article in powershell using:

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName FirstLookVault -ServicePrincipalName '06b430c8-3689-4b5f-b954-566affefbd0c' -PermissionsToSecrets get -PermissionsToKeys wrapKey, unwrapKey,decrypt,encrypt
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the access policy set to perform a `GET` of your key.

Comment: Yeah - you need to add the `get` operation.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/, specifically it is mentioned that you need to add the `get` policy if you want to be able to read the key.

Comment: Brendan, you were right.  I missed adding the GET to the policy when I created it in PowerShell.  I changed the policy and it is working fine.  You should set this as the answer.